# Alpha Channel in Eevee?

Tags: shaders, transparency, eevee-render-engine

Apologies in advance for the Eevee question... but!...now that the releases are getting more stable, I'm messing around with it and wondering if anyone has gotten an alpha channel/transparency mix shader to work with it.

Usual setup doesn't seem to work. It looks liek there was a transparency socket at some point, but not now, and plugging the alpha into the transmission does nothing.

Answer (score 14):

[image]Okay, if anyone else is wondering about this, I found an answer on Twitter of all places...there's an **Options** section of the **Materials** tab that contains a **Blend Mode** drop down with an **Alpha Blend** option (among others.)

Weird that this isn't accessible through the Node Editor somehow (but maybe I'm missing it.)

Comment: You can also get to those Options in the Node Editor's sidebar (by pressing N).