# EEVEE transparent mask is black instead of transparent

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine

I need to apply an alpha texture mask over a texture material in order to be transparent in the viewport. As is, it is black in EEVEE.

How do I modify this file to make the viewport show the mask as a transparent in the 3d view?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115159/alpha-channel-in-eevee?r=SearchResults

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alpha Channel in Eevee?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115159/alpha-channel-in-eevee)

Comment: well I have tried all these suggestions and still not working, but I am specifically using 'hair info' node with transparency shader, so maybe that has not been fixed yet

Answer (score 7):

For it to work I changed the Blend Mode to Apha Clip. That's all it needed for it to work.

Materials tab> Options> Blend Mode> Alpha Clip

Comment: Are you talking about the materials tab in the properties editor? I can't find any "options" in there.

Comment: @EspenSales It's in the Settings tab

Comment: Note: you must set this in EVEE, because LookDev works by using EVEE. Then you can set the Render Engine back to Cycles, for rendering.