# How to use texture alpha with Eevee?

Tags: shaders, transparency

In blender 2.79 I was able to create textures with and alpha channel and use them to make partially transparent materials.  I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing in 2.8.

Some online tutorials (about a year old) suggested using a mix shader to combine a transparent shader with a BDSF shader and using the alpha as a mask to blend the two.  Most of these tutorials want me to set the 'blend mode' in the material settings to 'alpha blend', but this setting does not appear to be present in the latest release.

[image]
How would I set up a basic shader using a texture with alpha?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115159/alpha-channel-in-eevee

Comment: I saw that.  My problem is that there is no Options/Blend Mode showing up in the Materials tab.

Comment: It's "Settings" and now you are in cycles render mode, that's why you can't find it.